# ubuntu server won't boot after restoring backup

Tags: 14.04, backup, restore

I have created a backup of my server using the following command:

`tar -cvzf ~/clone.tgz --exclude ~/clone.tgz  /etc /home /opt /tmp /usr /var`

Then I want to restore this backup to another server (same hardware except for the hard drive, which I upgraded to a a SSD). There is already a fresh install of the same ubuntu distribution.

I first did a backup of the following files:

- /etc/hosts
- /etc/hostname
- /etc/host.conf

So I run the following command :

`tar -xvpzf ~/clone.tgz -C /`

Once the files are restored, I restore the host files.

Everything seems fine so I reboot the server, but it won't boot. I don't have access to the server during boot since it is hosted from a remote location. All I can do is start all over again.

What might explain this problem ? Is there a file that I should not have overwritten during the restore ?

Comment: Your restore was a really bad idea :\

Answer (score 1):

**What is the problem**

You have a problem with `grub` and UUID in your `/etc/fstab`.

There is a line in `/etc/fstab` and `grub.cfg` like this:

```
..... UUID=73faad0d-2343-4f69-8103-92dbbaf40a5f .....
```

Each partition in Linux has unique identifier called `UUID`, it is assigned during partition creation. Linux use this `UUID` to distinguish partitions. After replacing hard drive you have to change all old UUIDs with the new ones, which can be checked by running command `blkid`.

**What to do**

You have to boot from Ubuntu Live CD and replace all old `UUID` to new `UUID` in `/etc/fstab` and `grub.cfg`. Here is another [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171446/how-to-fix-the-uuid-in-grub-after-restore-from-another-machine) where you can find further instructions. Then update `grub` using this [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd) or
simply [install and run Boot Repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) choosing *Recommended Repair* option.

Comment: I did not exclude the grub.cfg file, only the fstab. Maybe that could be it, I will try.

Comment: actually grub.cfg is in the /boot/grub folder. I did not overwrite the/boot folder as it is not part of the archive. That must not be the problem then.

Comment: @Sam you are right, if you do not restore /boot so grub is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

With the command `tar -xvpzf ~/clone.tgz -C /` you have restored **all**, `/etc`, `/home`, `/opt`, `/tmp`, `/usr`, `/var`.

I believe, you have more problems than a wrong UUID in your `/etc/fstab`.

- The full restore of `/etc`, problematic
- The full restore of `/usr`, bad idea
- The full restore of `/var`, bad idea

also on identical machines.

My piece of advice, install the server again.

Comment: I know that I've restored all files in these directories. I have the same hardware (except for the ssd). I tried a second restore, this time with the fstab file excluded, but same problem: it did not reboot. I find it annoying that linux mixes system config files with application config files in /etc. It makes it very hard to find out what to restore :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way:

- install fresh ubuntu server
- export list of installed packages on old server: 
  `dpkg --get-selections >output-file`
- import list  on new server:
  `sudo dpkg --set-selections <output-file 
  sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`

I just had a few users and permissions to set/create and a few application config files to copy across from the old server, but all in all it was very quick.